# Getting my Ruby file to load into Pry?

Tags: ruby, pry

I'm trying to edit my Ruby file with Pry. There are few variables that are set in it, and for whatever reason I can't seem to `cd` into them because they aren't being defined even after I 'load' the file.

Here is the code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri.XML('<foo><bar /><foo>', nil, 'UTF-8') 

url = "http://superbook.eventmarketer.com/category/agencies/" 

puts "Finished!"
```

In Pry I do:

```
load "./AgencyListingScraper.rb"
```

and then this is the output:

```
7] pry(main)> load './AgencyListingScraper.rb'
Finished!
=> true
[8] pry(main)>
```

Then when I try to do something like:

```
[8] pry(main)> url
NameError: undefined local variable or method `url' for main:Object
from (pry):6:in `__pry__'
[9] pry(main)> cd url
Error: Bad object path: url. Failed trying to resolve: url. #<NameError: undefined local     
variable or method `url' for main:Object>
[10] pry(main)>
```

This is what I get.

I think I'm not loading the file correctly although I've been searching for hours and I can't figure out how to properly do this. I was doing it right months ago when I had made a scraper with Ruby, but this time I'm having trouble just getting started because of this bit.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try it this way:

In your file include Pry and do a `binding.pry`:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pry'

doc = Nokogiri.XML('<foo><bar /><foo>', nil, 'UTF-8') 

url = "http://superbook.eventmarketer.com/category/agencies/" 

binding.pry
puts "Finished!"
```

Then run the file by executing:

```
ruby AgencyListingScraper.rb
```

That should drop you into a Pry session where you can use commands like `ls` to see all of the variables.

Both the way you used Pry, and this way, work. However, the reason that `load` may not be working in your case is that local variables don't get carried over across files, like when you require one file from another.

Try loading this file:

```
#test.rb
y = "i dont get carried over cause i am a local variable"
b= "i dont get carried over cause i am a local variable"
AAA= "i am a constant so i carry over"
@per = "i am an instance var so i get carried over as well"
```

When you load it in Pry using `load "test.rb"` you can see that you can't get access to the local variables from that file.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I didn't do this before. Any idea why I may not have needed to do this before?

Comment: both ways work, however, binding.pry is the my preferred way as you can still access your local variables. see the edits for more info! Glad to be of help

Comment: Ahh I see that about the local and instance variables. Thanks so much for your help. I'd have soon started to freak out without that extra knowledge.

Comment: Is it possible to load files into pry after some actions? Want to load multiple files during manually testing...

Answer (score 15):

I found this question googling but the proposed solution did not work for me because the file I wanted to load was not a class nor a script but a complex ruby config file, so I was not able to inject pry in the code.

But I also found an answer in Reddit linked to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/radarek/066307b304d18985b7c6) that was exactly what I was looking for.

Doing a

```
Pry.toplevel_binding.eval File.read("stuff.rb")
```

Will effectively execute the ruby code of the file `stuff.rb` in the current pry session, leaving the resulting objects for inspecting.